# Is there a way to test if all my reverse() calls in Django Views resolve?

Tags: django

I use `reverse('route_name')` in my views for redirection. If I do any refactoring of the urls, be it renaming the routes, moving some routes to other `urls.py` file or something similar, I will have to update all the route names in all my views. It is very easy to miss some of the files.

It seems trivial to simply `grep` all the `reverse()` calls from all the views and simply check if they resolve. The same thing with template files. It seems trivial to grep all the template names and check if they exist, or have they been moved or renamed and not updated in the views.

I'm wondering if there is already some kind of package that does this.

I've tried googling, but anything I search for focuses on writing specific tests. I'm wondering if there exists something that will help me avoid writing specific tests for each view.

For example:
Let's say I have a route: `path('/payments/cart', CartView.as_view(), name='payments-cart')`
If I decide to move the url definition into the `payments` app, the new name will be `cart` and the reversing of the url in the view will be done as `reverse('payments:cart')`. If any of my views still reference `payments-cart` instead of `payments:cart`, I wouldn't catch that error until the view tries to render. It's weird to me that there isn't already something that will catch that error without the need for writing specific tests for reversing the urls.